# How to log into Rancher bootstrap after installing using Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I installed Rancher on my Kubernetes cluster on Azure as described [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/install-rancher-on-k8s/aks/). I ran the following command:

```
helm install rancher rancher-latest/rancher --namespace cattle-system --set hostname=rancher.mydomain.com --set replicas=1 --set ingress.tls.source=secret --set bootstrapPassword=someRandomPassword
```

Rancher was installed successfully and when I opened the page at rancher.mydomain.com, it showed the admin login page. I tried the password I had used in the previous command but it wouldn't log in. I kept getting the error in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you try running the kubectl command shown on that page? It should print out the bootstrap password.

Comment: I did. It prints out the same password I had provided in the command. If you don't provide one, it generates a random password.

Comment: Can you scale down the Rancher deployment to 0 and then try scaling back up again? The password is supposed to be picked up from the bootstrap-secret.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work. I uninstalled and reinstalled Rancher a few times. It eventually got stuck after a few attempts. By that, I mean I wasn't able to delete the cattle-system namespace even though there were no k8s objects in it. I tried the workarounds proposed on Stackoverflow but no use so I had to recreate the whole AKS cluster which was quite painful. I'm not going to try rancher again until I make sure this won't happen again.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster?

Comment: I used the following CLI command to spin up the cluster:
`az aks create -n 'test-aks' -g 'test-group' --network-plugin azure --enable-managed-identity --generate-ssh-keys --kubernetes-version 1.20.7 --location 'AustraliaEast' --node-count 3 --nodepool-name 'agentpool' --node-vm-size Standard_B2ms --zones 1 2 -y --output none`

Comment: Did you try not providing your password in the command and use the generated one?

Comment: Yes but the generated password was blank.

Comment: @MarChal did you get answer to your problem. i am also suck with same situation, i am also getting same error "Invalid username or password. Please try again.
"

Comment: I didn't try again tbh. I don't want to have to recreate the whole cluster only because of Rancher. It was a pain in the a$$.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, without specifiying the password in the helm install it generates a blank password which won't work to login. After re-installing with a --set bootstrapPassword=password it still doesnt allow login, any updates????

Comment: I haven't tried again @pforsthoff. I kind of gave up on it

Answer (score 4):

@Mar Chal

Try below command to reset password it will work.

```
[]$ kubectl -n cattle-system exec $(kubectl -n cattle-system get pods -l app=demo-rancher | grep '1/1' | head -1 | awk '{ print $1 }') -- reset-password
W1214 11:55:25.230447     127 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
New password for default admin user (user-zkgpr):
oH9ySxxxxxxxxx7q_1767o
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with rancher 2.6.3 with helm installation. I had to run the below command to get admin password, apprarently the bootstrapPassword with helm set doesn't work. Poor rancher documentation!

*kubectl --kubeconfig $KUBECONFIG -n cattle-system exec $(kubectl --kubeconfig $KUBECONFIG -n cattle-system get pods -l app=rancher | grep '1/1' | head -1 | awk '{ print $1 }') -- ensure-default-admin*

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl get secret --namespace cattle-system bootstrap-secret -o go-template='{{.data.bootstrapPassword|base64decode}}{{"\n"}}'
```

try this one